# Mule DataMapper: How to add a Database Lookup table with dynamic connection parameter loading/reading from properties file

Tags: mule

I am currently using Mule ESB 3.4. to create a DataMapper with a database lookup table. It was working as the way I wanted to. But the value in the database lookup connection is hard coded now, which would be an issue when deploying to different servers (dev to prod). And I tried to find the way to make it to load/read from the properties files, but seems no luck. Usually, if you define a global connector, it would show up in the drop down list for you to choose, but the connection inside the datamapper using the database lookup table seems can not read the global connector information, I guess it is due to the fact that this setting is stored in the mapping file (the grf file) instead.

Is there a way to dynamically load/read the connection information from the properties file like: `${jdbc.user}` or any other way to make it dynamically load/read instead of hard-coded value??